# Can a profile picture have an alpha channel?

Tags: support, images, user-profile-page, avatar

This is really not very important, but it bugs me.

It seems impossible to get a profile picture with a transparent part. Even if I upload a picture with an alpha channel, the system seems to remove it. Note the (undesired) white background:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong here (aside from being too narcissistic, perhaps)?
Do you know a way of having a profile picture with an alpha channel?

EDIT: I've since found this informative  question on Meta Stack Overflow: [Profile picture cannot have transparent background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163831/profile-picture-cannot-have-transparent-background).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (I usually am), our avatars are managed by [Gravatar.com](https://gravatar.com) and currently neither alpha `.png`'s nor even animated `.gif`'s are supported. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda No, since two months you are not forced anymore to use Gravatar.com: [Announcing a new way to change your profile picture](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/). _(Yes, I know, it’s also linked in the Meta.SO question inserted above by jubob’s edit.)_

Comment: @Speravir: ah thanks, I was unaware of that new feature. `:)`

Comment: I think [N.N.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5701/n-n)’s picture has *nothing but* transparency in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally!

It seems that the [Imgur](http://imgur.com) system, which is now used for the "Uploaded picture" option in your profile page (see this [link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/)), does not support .png with an alpha channel. Every time I've tried to upload one, it was rendered with a white background on TeX.SE:

[image]

I was misled by this [2008 discussion](https://jeremy.visser.name/2008/03/alpha-blended-gravatars-broken/) about Gravatar's discontinued support for .png with an alpha channel. It turns out that they *do* support it, nowadays.

[image]

So, if you want a profile picture with an alpha channel, you need to use Gravatar (which is a bit of a pain). The procedure is detailed in this [meta.stackoverflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41278).

Comment: I need more than alpha. I need GIF. :-)

Comment: @Karl'sstudents No luck on this front, I'm afraid. GIF animations would be too distracting, though.

Comment: Yes, it's narcissism but I congratulate you on solving the problem!