# @-notification to a user who subsequently changes display name

Tags: support, feature-request

If I notify a user named Bob in a comment using `@Bob` and if Bob subsequently changes his display name to Alice, can the @-notification to Bob/Alice in my comment reflect that change?

Here is an example of what what I've experienced, recently. On the page of question [Can a profile picture have an alpha channel?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3407/can-a-profile-picture-have-an-alpha-channel), I notified, in one of my comment, a user whose display name was *Karl's Students* at the time. Subsequently, that user changed his/her display name to *Bugbusters*. However, as shown by the screenshot below, my comment still refers to the original display name (*Karl's Students*), not to the new one (*Bugsbusters*).

---

[image]

---

This may throw new visitors to that page completely off, because it now appears that I was replying to someone who never posted on that page in the first place!

The following links, which shed some light on the use of @ in Markdown to notify a user in a comment, do not seem to mention this issue:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020

Is there a way to make @-notifications reflect changes in display name?

Comment: See the Meta SO threads [Change all `@username` references in comments when a user changes their name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31851), [If I change my display name, will the change reflect in comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59884), and marginally also [Automatic removal of `@username` behaves incorrectly with changed user names](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98082).

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for the links. I didn't know of them, as I don't spend much time on meta.SO. It's too bad they don't implement what is suggested in the [accepted answer to your first link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31856).

Comment: Related: [Name changes remain in revision history](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2566/5764)

Comment: No matter whether or not the display change issue is fixed, we have still a problem when the comment to which we refer is removed.